What is the definition of Tr in the context of Hilbert modular forms?
I am currently reading Garrett's book "Holomorphic Hilbert Modular Forms". But I meet trouble at the starting line. Let $F = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt D)$ be a real quadratic field, $u= a + b\sqrt{D}\in F$, and $z = (z_1,z_2)\in \mathbb{H} \times \mathbb{H}$ where $\mathbb{H}$ denotes the upper half-plane. Then what is the definition of $\operatorname{Tr}(uz)$?
The book says "$\operatorname{Tr}$ is the $\mathbb{C}$-linear extension to $\mathbb{C}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ of the Galois trace $F \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$." But I don't understand what this means.
I know the Galois trace is $\operatorname{Tr}(u) = 2a$. Moreover, I found an explicit expression in the second page of Luo - Moments of the central L-values of the Asai lifts:
$$ \operatorname{Tr}(uz) = \frac{a + b\sqrt{D}}{\sqrt{D}}z_1 - \frac{a - b\sqrt{D}}{\sqrt{D}}z_2. $$
Could someone please explain how this expression fits into the definition of the trace used in the context of Hilbert Modular Forms?

Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now. Regarding high-level tags, see https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1075/

If $F$ is any totally real field of degree $r$ over $\mathbb Q$ and if
$\tau=(\tau_1,\dotsc,\tau_r)\in \mathbb H^r$, by definition it is usual to
define $\operatorname{Tr}(u\tau)=u^{(1)}\tau_1+\cdots u^{(r)}\tau_r$, where
the $u^{(i)}$ denote the $r$ embeddings of $F$ into $\mathbb R$.
However, the Fourier expansion at infinity of a holomorphic Hilbert modular form is of the form
$$f(\tau)=a(0)+\sum_{0\ll u\in{\frak d}^{-1}}a(u)e^{2\pi i\operatorname{Tr}(u\tau)}$$
where the sum is over totally positive elements of the codifferent.
In the special case when the codifferent is a principal ideal generated by
some element $\delta\in O_F$, as in the case of quadratic fields, one can
write $u=v/\delta$ and now sum on $v\in O_F$ instead. In that case
$\operatorname{Tr}(u\tau)=\operatorname{Tr}(v\tau/\delta)$. But it is a bad
idea to define the trace specifically for the case of quadratic fields
(where $\delta=\sqrt{D}$) as the reference that you mention seems to do,
since it does not seem to be generalizable to arbitrary totally real fields.

Thank you for your clear response! It has helped me understand the concept much better. Additionally, I have had the pleasure of studying your textbook 'Number Theory' in a discussion group, and it has been a valuable resource for our learning. (^▽^)

$\DeclareMathOperator\Tr{Tr}$I think that it means that we regard $F \otimes_{\mathbb Q} \mathbb C$ as a 2-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb C$ by action on the second factor.  Then $\Tr((a + b\sqrt D) \otimes z)$ equals $z\Tr(a + b\sqrt D) = 2a z$, by definition.
If we define $F \otimes_{\mathbb Q} \mathbb C \to \mathbb C^2$ by $v \otimes z \mapsto (v z, \overline v z)$, where $\overline\cdot$ is the Galois conjugation of $F/\mathbb Q$, then we may transport the natural $\mathbb C$-linear action of $F$ on the source to such an action on the target.  Specifically, $(z_1, z_2) \in \mathbb C^2$ is the image of $$\frac1 2(1 \otimes z_1 + \sqrt D \otimes z_1\sqrt D^{-1}) + \frac1 2(1 \otimes z_2 - \sqrt D \otimes z_2\sqrt D^{-1}),$$ so that $u(z_1, z_2)$ is the image of $$\frac1 2(u \otimes z_1 + u\sqrt D \otimes z_1\sqrt D^{-1}) + \frac1 2(u \otimes z_2 - u\sqrt D \otimes z_2\sqrt D^{-1}),$$ whose trace in the sense above is $$\frac1 2(z_1 + z_2)\Tr(u) + \frac1{2\sqrt D}(z_1 - z_2)\Tr(u\sqrt D).$$  If $u$ equals $a + b\sqrt D$, then this last equals
$$
\frac1 2(z_1 + z_2)(2a) + \frac1{2\sqrt D}(z_1 - z_2)(2b D) = %(z_1 + z_2)a + (z_1 - z_2)b\sqrt D =
(a + b\sqrt D)z_1 + (a - b\sqrt D)z_2.
%\tag{$*$}\label{481799_star}
$$
This agrees with the formula in @HenriCohen's answer, since, in the notation there, we can number the real embeddings so that $u^{(1)} = a + b\sqrt D$ and $u^{(2)} = a - b\sqrt D$.  It is off by a factor of $\sqrt D$ from the explicit expression in the reference.  I did not find the formula there on a quick scan, so cannot explain the discrepancy, but it could come simply from a different identification of $F \otimes_{\mathbb Q} \mathbb C$ with $\mathbb C^2$.

Thank you very much for your detailed answer! It's quite creative, and I haven't seen anything similar before.
